# Android Trun on backlight

Tags: android

I need to turn on screen back-light and keyboard backlight when my application receive notification. I have tried with PowerManager It it wasn't successful.

Is there any way to turn on screen and keyboard backlights?

Thank You.

Comment: A snippet of code might help you get a good answer...Are you using this with an AlarmManager?

Comment: No No I haven't used AlarmManager. I used PowerManager it Turn on backlight.

Comment: Hi is any one know how to fixed this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue.

```
 private void backlightON(Context context){
          PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
          PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |  PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "MessageReader");
          wakeLock.acquire();
}
```